# Is it possible to track uploaded file location?

Tags: upload

Sometimes i upload files to a website like attachments ..
The websites doesn't tell me where was the file uploaded
but it says yes it was uploaded
as im the uploader, is it possible to track the file location ?
whats the path of it in the website ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take stack overflow for example. If you upload an image as part of a question or answer, then the image is displayed on the screen when viewing the relevant item.  If its being displayed in your browser, you can always find the URL by using your favorite web development toolkit.

So if you can access the resource in the browser, you have a url.

That doesn't necessarily translate into the exact location on the site's server, however.  There is no way to know for sure where it is kept.

And if you upload something and it is never displayed back to you, there is no way to know.

Whether or not you have the *right* to know is a different matter entirely.  It probably depends on the site's EULA.  But as an opinion, noone forces you to upload anything.  If you choose to do so, I think you give up the right to know where they put your contribution.